# is it possible to transfer x,y,z data from Lua to Unity3d?

Tags: sockets, unity-game-engine, lua, udp, communication

I implemented simulation by using Lua script.
I want to send the data(x,y,z position information) to Unity3D.
I will use UDP communication.
Unity3D = C#, Lua are different language.
is it possible to transfer x,y,z data from Lua to Unity3d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Network applications will always be able communicate with each other as long as they use standard protocol. UDP and TCP are both standardized, so no matter what programming language you use, they can both talk to each other.

Comment: yes , and if you can create a lua server you can get data using unity's www class

Comment: @LumbusterTick close but Unity's www class is for web(http). web is different from UDP. He needs C# `UdpClient` class or raw `socket` class.

Comment: hmm but doesnt a server takes http requests? I mean i made one using java , but sorry mb i skipped the udp  part , thanks

Comment: @LumbusterTick there many type of servers. There is tcp,udp,http and they are all different protocols. if you create a `udp` server, you will only be able to connect/broadcast to it with `udp` client. If you create a tcp server you must connect to it with a `tcp` client. The tricky part: If you create a `http` server, you can connect to it with `httpclient` (Unity's `www`) or with `tcp`. Although it's complicated to connect to `http` with `tcp` because you need to know how `http` is implemented with `tcp` but it is possible. So you can't connect to `udp` with the `www` class.